# Dynamic row selection based on a condition

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic, dom-manipulation

[image]In this scenario, I have to iterate thru all table rows and select first instance of the row wherein it has a warning indicator as shown in the image attached. 
Rows with warning indicator will have additional div as mentioned below.

Comment: I have written a helping code to get an idea that how can you go about it. Let me know if you don't understand something out of it.

Answer (score 1):

As I can't see your complete **DOM** clearly, I will give you an idea how can you go about iterating through these rows and return the row with warning associated -

```
var allTr = document.getElementsByClassName("classNameOnTr");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(allTr, function(tr) {
    // all tds within a tr
    var trAllTd = tr.children;

    // first td out of all
    var firstTd = trAllTd[0];

    if(firstTd.children[0]) {
        // this is the probable div which creates the warning indicator
        // write your logic to check if the div exist here
        // break the loop if you find it here and return the td
    }
});
```

`Note:` I have written lengthy code to give you more idea how can you go about it. You can shorten it in a line or two if you understood it well.